# Macro to get the type of an expression

Tags: c++, templates, types, macros, type-traits

### Question

I am trying to write a C++ macro that would take either *`type`* or *`type name`* as input, and give *`type`* as output.

For example:
`REMOVE_NAME(int)` should be `int`
`REMOVE_NAME(int aNumber)` should also be `int`

I managed to write such a macro (below) and it works, but I'm wondering whether I'm missing a simpler way to accomplish this.

```
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template <typename T>
struct RemoveNameVoidHelper
{
    typedef typename T::arg1_type type;
};

template <>
struct RemoveNameVoidHelper<boost::function_traits<void()>>
{
    typedef void type;
};

#define REMOVE_NAME(expr) RemoveNameVoidHelper<boost::function_traits<void(expr)>>::type
```

Any ideas?

### Motivation

I'm using this macro to aid with code generation. I have another macro which is used to declare certain methods in class definitions:

```
#define SLOT(name, type)                            \
    void Slot##name(REMOVE_NAME(type) argument)     \
    {                                               \
        /* Something that uses the argument. */     \
    }                                               \
    void name(type)
```

I want the user of the `SLOT` macro to be able to comfortably choose whether he wants to implement his slots inside or outside the class, just like with normal methods. This means that `SLOT`'s type argument can be either a type, or a type with a name. For example:

```
class SomeClass
{
    SLOT(ImplementedElsewhere, int);
    SLOT(ImplementedHere, int aNumber)
    {
        /* Something that uses aNumber. */
    }
};
```

Without the `REMOVE_NAME` macro, my automatically generated `Slot...` method will not be able to specify its own name for its argument, and thus it will not be able to refer to it.

Of course, this is not the only possible use for this macro.

Comment: Yeah. Simpler would be to: not use a MACRO for this. Or if you do, just specify the name separately?!

Comment: Check out [`decltype`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decltype).

Comment: why? Could you use C++ 11 decltype?

Comment: `decltype(int aNumber)` is illegal, unfortunately.

Comment: If you want something "simpler" it would help if you could explain what you want this for, and how you plan to use it.

Comment: Added the motivation for the question.

Comment: (Refers to a deleted comment) I don't hardcode the name of the argument. The implementation of `ImplementedHere` goes under the line `void ImplementedHere(int aNumber)`. The hardcoded name `argument` is only used in the macro-generated function `void SlotImplementedHere(int argument)` which the library user knows nothing about. I have to use a hardcoded name there, or the implementation of `AsyncImplementedHere` (which is also generated right there in the macro) would not be able to refer to its own parameter.

Comment: (Refers to a deleted comment) The `SLOT` macro is indeed variadic (not shown here), and when users implement their slot they specify complete arguments. That's why the implementation of `ImplementedHere` can refer to `aNumber`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're correct; as far as I can tell the only other production where a *decl-specifier-seq* or *type-specifier-seq* is followed by an optional *declarator* is a `catch` statement, and I don't think that's much use for type extraction.  The production *parameter-declaration* is also used in *template-parameter-list*, but that's not much use either.

I might define your macro like this, removing the dependency on Boost:

```
template<typename T> struct remove_name_helper {};
template<typename T> struct remove_name_helper<void(T)> { typedef T type; };
template<> struct remove_name_helper<void()> { typedef void type; };

#define REMOVE_NAME(expr) typename remove_name_helper<void(expr)>>::type
```

Comment: Thanks! This really is better. By the way, the void specialization is unnecessary with your implementation - it was only necessary to work around the fact that boost doesn't define arg1_type when the function has no parameters.