# Deduce the type of a declaration

Tags: c++, macros, type-deduction

I am writing a macro that takes a declaration as its single argument. Is it possible to **deduce the type of the declaration** inside the macro without splitting up the single argument into separate *type* and *identifier* arguments?

```
#define M(declaration) \
    declaration;       \
    static_assert(sizeof(/* deduce type of 'declaration' */) == 4, "!")

M(int i);
M(double d{3.14});
M(std::string s{"Hello, world!"});
```

The following implementation would work but it feels less user-friendly (imo):

```
#define M(type, identifier) \
    type identifier;        \
    static_assert(sizeof(type) == 4, "!")

M(int, i);
M(double, d{3.14});
M(std::string, s{"Hello, world!"});
```

If possible, I would prefer to take the declaration as a single argument.

---

**Related question:** [Macro to get the type of an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248717/macro-to-get-the-type-of-an-expression); but I failed to get that code to work in my example (compiler error: *expected nested-name-specifier*).

Comment: Do you intend for the static assert to print the identifier in the end? Because if not, there's a solution that also ditches the preprocessor.

Comment: @StoryTeller I would not necessarily need the identifier. But if you can think of multiple solutions, I would be interested in all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your static assertion message is really that simple `"!"`<sup>1</sup>, I suggest you ditch the preprocessor. Make the type system work for you instead:

```
namespace detail {
  template<typename T>
  struct check_declared_type {
    using type = T;
    static_assert(sizeof(type) == 4, "!");
  };
}

template<typename T>
using M = typename detail::check_declared_type<T>::type;

// .. Later

int main() {
  M<int> i;
  M<double> d{3.14};
  M<std::string> s{"Hello, world!"};
}
```

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> - Specifically, if you don't need the preprocessor to stringify anything for you.</sub>

Comment: This solves my problem and lets me avoid macros, thanks! Do you also have a solution if I wanted to use the identifier in the `static_assert`?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis - That would require hauling the pre-processor back in. And it takes you back to square 1.

Comment: So can I then conclude that it is not possible to deduce the type of a declaration in C++? Not even with a clever combination of `decltype` and other compile-time tricks?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis - Not to my knowledge. A declaration is not an expression, so it cannot appear in an unevaluated context. Maybe the pre-processor *can* break it apart. But I am not familiar with the technique.

Answer (score 1):

This macro ought to work for all your examples, but it does have a nasty issue:

```
#define M(declaration) \
    declaration;       \
    do { \
        struct dummy__ { declaration; }; \
        static_assert(sizeof(dummy__) == 4, "!"); \
    } while (false)
```

The problem is that an initializer within a class definition must use either the `=` token or a braced-init-list at top level, and not parentheses at top level.  So for example `M(SomeClass obj(true, 3));` won't compile, even if `sizeof(SomeClass)==4`.  Since braced initializers are not entirely equivalent to parenthesis initializers, this means some declarations would be impossible to use with the macro.